# d3.js foreach loop on all the paths contained in a svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have a svg generated by d3.js like this one:

```
<svg height="1094" width="1254">
    <g id="countries" stroke-width="1px" transform="">
        <path d="M100,519.150,200,250" fill="rgba(100,100,100,0.8)"
        stroke="rgba(200,200,200,0.5)" id="id1" class="1"></path>
        <path d="M100,519.150,200,250" fill="rgba(100,100,100,0.8)"
        stroke="rgba(200,200,200,0.5)" id="id2" class="1"></path>
        <path d="M100,519.150,200,250" fill="rgba(100,100,100,0.8)"
        stroke="rgba(200,200,200,0.5)" id="id3" class="3"></path>
        <path d="M100,519.150,200,250" fill="rgba(100,100,100,0.8)"
        stroke="rgba(200,200,200,0.5)" id="id4" class="1"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want to do somtehing like that :

```
foreach(path in #countries){
    if(this.class === 3){dostuff}
}
```

I've tried the jquery way :

```
$('#countries').find('path').each(function( index ) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

... log nothing

I've tried the d3.js way (countries was initialized as follow : `countries = svg.append('svg:g').attr('id', 'countries')` ):

```
countries.select('path').each(console.log(this));
countries.selectAll('path').each(console.log(this));
```

log the window object (wtf?)

Comment: most probably `countries` is not unique id in your code, can you make fiddle to demostrate problem ? Because [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6LyVz/) works well

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The method [selection.each](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) requires a function as argument:

```
countries.selectAll('path').each(function(d,i) { console.log(this); });
```